# Extended Global Approximation Theorem

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

In Evans,

> $\textbf{Theorem} $ (Global Approximation Theorem) Assume $U$ is bounded, and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Suppose as well that $u \in W^{k,p}(U)$ for some $1\leq p < \infty$. Then, there exist functions $u_m \in C^{\infty}(\bar{U})$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> u_m \rightarrow u \quad \textrm{ in } W^{k,p}(U)
> \end{align*}

$\textbf{Question}$ Although we change the boundary condition like
\begin{align*}
\partial U=\bigcup_{j=1}^n \Gamma_j, \quad (\textrm{boundary is piecewise } C^{1})
\end{align*}
where each $\Gamma_j$ for $j=1, \cdots, n$ is a $C^1$, $\Gamma_j$ and $\Gamma_{j^{'}}$ do not intersect except at their endpoints if $j\neq j'$, then does the theorem still hold?

Any help is appreciated!!

I want to know references related that...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

*... does the theorem still hold?*

Smooth boundary is not needed. The theorem is true provided that the domain does not lie on both sides of any part of its boundary, i.e., provided that $U$ satisfies the [segment condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2007607/70305).

Reference: [Adams book, p. 68](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&pg=PA68&dq=%22The+difficulty+with+the+domain+in+this+example+is+that+it+lies+on+both+sides+of+part%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK6tr2r_LeAhXEi5AKHdTdAEwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20difficulty%20with%20the%20domain%20in%20this%20example%20is%20that%20it%20lies%20on%20both%20sides%20of%20part%22&f=false).